# Why CURL picks half of the URL for request?

Tags: php, curl

The error the following code give is

HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request: Invalid HTTP Version in Request Line. 
Line: GET /http/send-message?to=233445566&message=Some String

```
    $curl = curl_init();
     curl_setopt_array($curl, 
     array( CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 4,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
                    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://GATEWAY:9710/http/send-message?to='.$mobileNumber.'&message='.$message

     ));
```

Let me know what is going on?

Comment: I can't tell from what you posted but are you urlencoding the $message?

Comment: Set the version to `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0` and try again.

Comment: @Jack,i tried it did not work.

Comment: @noko, URL Ecoding did the trick, :) THanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

That's not cURL, that's how HTTP works - the domain portion of the URL is passed in the `Host:` header, not the request. The request itself starts at the first `/` after the domain.

The error you're getting back appears to be due to the fact that you're explicitly setting HTTP 1.1, and the server is a 1.0 server.

*Edit*: Looks like your problem was solved in the comments above. In general, urlencoding things you're going to put in a URL is useful. :)